# Images within show c# code that I am confused about

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2012, linq-to-sql, integration

The picture below shows a integration test I am working on at the moment.

1.http://i44.tinypic.com/n1atk4.png

What is so confusing to me is that the line:

```
Assert.AreEqual(0/*57*/, auditRecord.Table_Final_Row_Count);
```

The `/* 57 */` is the value that is should actually be (just commented out).

This picture below is the results within the database:

2.http://i39.tinypic.com/117foyx.png

---

A little more info:
I am converting hundreds of lines of code to linq2sql. The unconverted code has /*57*/ as the result that should be correct. When I try to add the 57 it gives me an error stating Expected(57) Actual (0). Now I know 0 is not correct.. It is probably my code. How can I fix this?

P.S. With the zero it successfully passes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test is brittle. You are returning the first element from the database without a predicate or an order clause. It's not guaranteed that the SQL Server will return the same rows when you use `SELECT TOP(1)`. Probably the previous test run returned value of 57 for that column. You should change the FirstOrDefault() call.

```
var auditRecord = auditRecords.FirstOrDefault(row => row.Id == someId);
```

Or:

```
var auditRecord = auditRecords..OrderBy(row => row.SomeColumn).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: it is brittle because I only have roughly 2-3 months experience in this type of programming. getting better..

Comment: any hints you could give me for the line:

//Assert.AreEqual(int.Parse(dAudit.Rows[0][5].ToString()), int.Parse(dResults.Rows[0][1].ToString()));

Comment: @user3066171 Looks like the same problem. Trying to guess the items without any ordering. It also gets the column values using their indexes. No one can understand what this assertion is doing without checking the column indexes from DB. Since you are using L2SQL you should be able to write the same assertion by using Audit objects.

Comment: What do you mean "no one can understand what this assertion is doing without checking the column indexes from the DB" What exactly is it within the index that I am looking for?

Comment: @user3066171 `dAudit.Rows[0][5]` means fifth column of the first row I think. That could be any row, I will have to check the DB to see which one.

Comment: Ahhh! Can I post a question with all of the info needed to explain this? and could you take the time to review it?

Comment: @user3066171 If you want to code review, take a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I never even knew that existed :O

Comment: posted! http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36710/integration-testing-c-vs2012-please-review 

I linked it because I didnt see my question in the newest section.